# WPF and MVVM. Display and hide a label with a timeout

Tags: wpf, mvvm, popup, timeout, show-hide

in my MVVM application, I wish to create an auto-closing popup to notify some information to the users (for example "data changes saved successfully").
so, I placed a label into the form, bound to a VM property. Then, I wish to set my message and cancel it after a delay (1 second). But it seems not to work. the app just wait some time, and shows the final status (ie: when the user push "save" button, the app "waits" for one second, and then the label is empty).
any ideas to get it? thanks

Comment: Have a look at this answer - you can tweak it slightly for your use case.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51039348/show-current-time-wpf/51043116#51043116

Comment: It probably doesn't work because you don't have any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you use normal popup in WPF

```
<Popup Margin="10,10,0,13" Name="Popup1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" Height="200" IsOpen="True">  
    <StackPanel>  
        <TextBlock Name="McTextBlock"   
         Background="LightBlue" >  
        This is popup text   
       </TextBlock>  
        <Button Content="This is button on a Pupup" />  
    </StackPanel>
```

```
public void show()
{
  Popup1.IsOpen = true;
  Thread t = new Thread(hide);
  t.Start();
}

private void hide() {
  Thread.Sleep(5000);
  Popup1.IsOpen = false;
}
```

call show function when you want to show popup