# WPF - A more accurate Timer

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, time, dispatchertimer

I'm new to CS and WPF. I'm going to get a `DateTime` object and set it as the beginning of my timer. But I used `DispatcherTimer.Tick`. I can feel it inaccurate with a little care and playing with window controls. It apparently its in a single thread beside other functions of program.

```
 DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
 timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
 timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
 timer.Start();

 void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {  
     dateTime = dateTime.AddSeconds(1);
     TimeTb.Text = dateTime.ToLongTimeString();
 }
```

Is there another method to use for a more accurate timer?

Comment: How "accurate" does your timer need to be? ~15ms of resolution is plenty good for 99% of use cases. Ignoring anything else, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744032/why-are-net-timers-limited-to-15-ms-resolution will probably shed some light for you.

Comment: The DispatcherTimer is only useful to get the Text property updated periodically.  Its actual interval is not critical, albeit that when you use *exactly* one second then you get to see what the Nyquist sampling theorem says.  Using 100 msec is a reasonable compromise to human eyes.

Comment: Have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51039348/show-current-time-wpf/51043116#51043116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely. Take a look at the [`System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) class. You're re-inventing the wheel!

Comment: I could not take the right way to use this class. Can u show an example?

Comment: @F4125h4d: Did you look?  Sorry, but the help for the class includes a sample that pretty much shows everything.  Create a Stopwatch, call Start on it, call Stop, then get myStopwatch.Elapsed and turn it into a TimeSpan object.  I could write some code, but it would look an awful lot like that sample.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Do not add up seconds. This is accurate:

```
private TimeSpan offset;

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    TimeTb.Text = (DateTime.Now - offset).ToLongTimeString();
}
```

If you want to show the time elapsed since a start time:

```
private DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    TimeTb.Text = (DateTime.Now - start).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Then subtract an appropriate TimeSpan. Your approach requires *infinite* accuracy, something that doesn't exist.